# Homestead is always served on localhost, Homestead.yaml configuration is ignored

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, vagrant, homestead

I [installed Homestead](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/homestead#installation-and-setup) and everything seems to run correctly, but my project is always served on localhost:8000 although the ip address in Homestead.yaml is set to the default "192.168.10.10":

```
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 2
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/Code
      to: /home/vagrant/Code

sites:
    - map: homestead.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/public
```

When I go to homestead.app I see the 'Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page'. Is something conflicting here?
[image]

My /etc/hosts:

```
192.168.10.10   homestead.app
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   ubuntu-machine

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

I used `vagrant up --provision` after every change and
I'm using Homestead v5.1.0 on Ubuntu 17.04.

Comment: Homestead by default uses nguni instead of apache, so it sounds like your browser is attempting to load your OS's web server instead.

Comment: Oy, meant nginx, not nguni. Auto-correct is weird.

Comment: hi did you already found a solution to this I get the same problem